# The "Add New" Plugin button does not appear on Wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, plugins

On my WordPress dashboard, I am unable to see the ADD NEW plugin button.
The Plugin menu when over PLUGINS is not here also.
[image: screenshot of wordpress dashboard]

1. I check the theme by desactivate the current theme and activate default theme but the ADD NEW button still not appears.
2. I check the installed plugins by desactivate them all and reactivate one by one, but the problem still here.
3. I check the wp-config.php file but there are not

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);
```

I try to add

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',false);
```

but it does not work.

Can someone have an idea about this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try reinstalling WordPress.** Possibly your wp core files effected from one of your plugins. Reinstalling WordPress may help,

Comment: Wordpress updated and the ADD NEW plugin button appears now. Problem was just with update. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

So you are facing this reason :

1) May be memory issue.

Try to increase memory :

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

2) User Role Restrictions

Check your user role. Are you performing as admin or not ?

3) You are on multi-site network.

Check your WordPress installation are you on multisite network or not

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your advices: 1. increase memory --> Add New plugin button still not appears. 2. I have the administrator access 3. the WP installation is not a multisite. I do not understand why this Add New plugin button is not displayed.

Comment: As silly as it sounds, in my case it was the Network. I was on the plugins page for one of the network sites, and the button was (obviously, now) not showing. All I had to do was go to *My Sites* → *Network Admin* → *Plugins* and the *Add New* button was there.

Answer (score 0):

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', false);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

It's work for me.